# jquery display template with no data

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have a template in jquery and trying to display just the HTML with no data. I tried to bind 'null' instead of the json "data" but it gives error (Address is undefined). Below is code statement.

```
$("#empTemplate").tmpl(null).appendTo("#divEmp");
```

HTML Markup:

```
<table style="padding-left: 5px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>Name:</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span>Employer:</span>
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span>1</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{if Address.Length >=1}}
                                    <input type="text" value="${Address[0].State}" style="width: 50px" />
                                    {{else}}
                                    <input type="text" value="" style="width: 50px" />
                                    {{/if}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{if Address.Length >=2}}
                                    <input type="text" value="${Address[1].State}" style="width: 50px" />
                                    {{else}}
                                    <input type="text" value="" style="width: 50px" />
                                    {{/if}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{if Address.Length >=3}}
                                    <input type="text" value="${Address[2].State}" style="width: 50px" />
                                    {{else}}
                                    <input type="text" value="" style="width: 50px" />
                                    {{/if}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
```

Here is the Json as well:

```
{
    "Name": "Peter",
    "EmpId": "10",
    "Employer": [
        {
            "EmpName": "ABC",
            "EmpCity": "Jal",
            "Address": [
                {
                    "State": "MO",
                    "City": "St.Louis" 
                } 
            ] 
        } 
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where are you intending for `Address` to be referenced from?

Comment: Address is an Array that is part of the Employee object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an empty object `{address:[]}`

```
$("#empTemplate").tmpl({address:[]}).appendTo("#divEmp");
```

Comment: @Luke: Do you mean to create an empty JSON object and bind it?

Comment: Great! It works, but why is the template not able to handle arrays that are nulls?

Comment: Well, in that case, how are the objects like Name, EmpId etc. getting handled? Even they are nulls, right?

Comment: in my solition, there is no object "{}" that has the propertynames name empid. if you try do address[index].Name on an array, where the array doesnt exist, you will get array out of range error. if there is an object, like {}, then it would say name is not defined, since there os not property like this. You should tell me, why you want to do all this, and what you want to reach.